# How to set a port as input or output with PIC?

Tags: pic

**Problem : Cannot understand how to set port A and port B as input and output**

Im using a book as reference : *page 19 - Introduction (chapter) - BookName : John Morton Third Edition - The PIC MicroController Your Personal Introductory Course*

According to what I understood from the book,bit numbering goes from right to left, so im supposed to read as port DCBA and thats why : b'0010'

However, this paragraph on *page 18* is really confusing :

> It moves the literal into the working register. Then the instruction
>   tris takes the number in the working register and uses it to select
>   which bits of the port are to act as inputs and which as outputs. A
>   binary 1 will correspond to an input and a 0 corresponds to an output.

And reading it again,I wonder if , for each port, there is 4 bits, and I can select how many of these are input and how many are output? But I thought a port can only be output or input..

Please , would someone clarify?

```
__config _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _XT_OSC
list P = 16F57;
include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v3.40\mpasmx\p16f57.inc";


portA equ 05
portB equ 06
org 0 ; Starts at 0?
goto Start


Init  
    clrf portA ; Reset Port A and B States
    clrf portB ;
    movlw b'0010'; Set port B as output
    tris portA;
    movlw b'0010'; Set Port A as input 
    ;0010 should mean -> ABCD port states?
    tris portB;
    retlw 0; return

Start 
    call Init;

Main
    bsf portA,0;

goto Main;

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An individual port corresponds to all of its associated pins.  For example, on the PIC16F57, you have pins RA0,RA1,RA2 and RA3.  These pins correspond to PORTA bits 0, 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  So, this is what is actually happening.

```
clrf portA
clrf portB
movlw b'0010'  ;Set RA1 as input and RA0,RA2,RA3 as output
tris portA;
movlw b'0010'  ;Set RB1 as input and RB0,RB2,RB3 as output
tris portB
```

Something to note is that all pins are initialized as inputs upon power up or reset and, while PORTA is only a 4 bit register, PORTB is 8 bits. In this case it may be better to explicitly declare all of the bits for that register.

```
movlw b'00000010'  ;Set RB1 as input all others as output.
tris portB
```

You have to make sure that you read the datasheet to determine the width of your PORT registers and their corresponding pins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why theres a definition of "port" if i can use "pins" to connect the chip to the outside world?

Comment: @ScientistGirl - That is because each bit of the port corresponds to an individual pin - you still have to reference the correct port register in order to use a pin.  For example, in the code above, RA0 has been set to an output.  Now, if I want to set that output to a high level, I would need to set the associated bit within the PORTA register like this `BSF PORTA, 0`.  To set the output to a low I would use `BCF PORTA, 0`.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that you are working with an 8-bit microcontroller.  It would have been possible for the designer of the chip to use an entire register for a single pin, but that would be a waste of seven bits (as only 1 bit is needed for a pin).  In order to be more efficient, it makes sense to have an 8-bit register, wherein each bit is associated with an individual pin - it saves on space.  I would encourage you to look at the datasheet [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41213D.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

```
TRISB=0xFF; //For PortB as a Input
TRISB=0x00; //For PortB as Output
```